# VS Code - IntelliSense: settings

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is it possible to turn off some suggestions? For example I don't need almost any suggestion for interfaces.

It's annoying so many options and when I write something what's included in HTML something.. and click Tab I get this interface suggestion which I really don't use at all.

Screenshot of wrong suggestion:

[image: Screenshot of wrong suggestion]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code 1.19 solves this with smarter IntelliSense.